# How to get the last but one element of an Iterator (Java)

Tags: java, iterator

I'm curios about how an Iterator works. My current goal is to get the last but one element of an Iterator in Java. Is there a way to get this element without changing the Iterator to a Array or List? 
 And if it's possible how there must be a way to get the last but n element of an Iterator.

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1):

If the `functionThatThrowsStackOverflowError` method is throwing the error, then your test case should work.

You can try following example and then replace the `testMethod()` with your `functionThatThrowsStackOverflowError` method to narrow down the root cause,

```
@Test(expected = StackOverflowError.class)
public void testError() {
    testMethod();
}

private void testMethod() {
    throw new StackOverflowError("Error!");
}
```